# Algorithm to compute "median"

Tags: calculus, geometry, statistics, euclidean-geometry, median

Let $x_1,\dots,x_m\in\mathbb{R}^d$ be a finite set of points.  I define the $d$-dimensional "median" $y\in\mathbb{R}^d$ to be the point minimizing the sum of distances to $x_j$,
$$
y = \arg\min_{z\in\mathbb{R}^d} \sum_{j=1}^m |z-x_j|.
$$
(Note that the median might not exist, for example if $x_j$ lie on a straight line).

Is there an efficient algorithm to compute $y$?  For example, when $m=3$ and $d=2$ there is a construction for the Fermat point of a triangle, which is what I am calling the median here.

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_median#Computation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be looking for Weiszfeld's algorithm, mentioned [here](https://www.web.pdx.edu/%7Emnn3/FT.pdf).

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.